# Displaying HTML popups for feature service

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

This bit of information caught my eye today as I was reading about Feature Services in the ArcGIS Server .NET help:

> Feature services also support HTML
>   pop-ups setup in ArcMap. HTML pop-ups
>   are a powerful and easy way to share
>   HTML formatted information about
>   features. They work much like the
>   Identify tool, except that the
>   information display can be customized
>   HTML.

I set up the HTML popup in ArcMap and it worked as expected, and then I published a map service.  The REST endpoint of my service now shows esriServerHTMLPopupTypeAsURL as the HTML Popup Type, however, I can't seem to find a sample, etc. that shows how to display the popup in a web application.

Does anyone have a link to a sample, or some sample code, that can show me how to do this?  I have looked through the JavaScript API samples/reference and didn't find what I was looking for (or what I thought I should be looking for).

Thanks,
Tim

**Edit:**  Thanks to those who supplied answers for the links.  I think I need to re-phrase the question:  I'm not having problems getting the popup to display - that is working fine.  My HTML popup type is set as PopupTypeAsURL, so I was expecting the popup to display the contents of the URL, say http://whateversite.com.  Essentially I want the popup to display a web page or web form.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FeatureServers expose an [htmlPopup](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/fs-htmlPopup.html) resource for each feature. Displaying the popup using Javascript would be very easy. Simply send a get request with a format parameter of "json." The "content" key in the returned object contains the full HTML markup for the popup window.

The see an HTML popup example, go to http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Hydrography/Watershed173811/FeatureServer/1/1/htmlPopUp

To see the JSON version of the same popup resource, go to http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Hydrography/Watershed173811/FeatureServer/1/1/htmlPopUp?f=json

You might also consider the [InfoWindow dijit](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jsapi_start.htm#jsapi/infowindow.htm) in the Javascript framework API. This window gives you a configurable way to display attribute information for features loaded from a FeatureService and it works with the [IdentifyTask](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jsapi_start.htm#jsapi/identifytask.htm) which is a plus. Be aware, however, that the IdentifyWindow does not look at the htmlPopup that you have configured for a feature class.

Answer (score 1):

I have these links too, but for flex:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/flex/samples/index.html?sample=FeatureLayer_InfoWindow

http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/flex/samples/index.html?sample=InfoSymbolBasics

That should demonstrate what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

http://geochalkboard.wordpress.com/2008/10/23/attaching-an-infowindow-to-graphics-with-the-arcgis-server-javascript-api/

Hope that helps.